# Подсчитать количество слов ВСЕХ 'Proc' в таблице test

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, count

Как мне быстро подсчитать количество ВСЕХ слов "Proc" в таблице test? 
Я думал что это будет выглядеть как подсчет количества строк в `POSTGRE SQL` таблице. `SELECT (*) FROM test;`

Но это не так, и я не знаю как быстро подсчитать количество ВСЕХ слов в таблице и вывести затем цифру на экран (количество слов)

PS: Слово - набор букв без спец символов и цифр

Comment: вот пример как в одной строке посчитать https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708237/5669174 остается добавить группировку и сделать sum() этого показателя

Comment: правда вы не уточнили что такое 'слово', отличается ли у вас это понятие от скажем "подстрока". Через regexp_matches вполне можно даже слова отыскать, хотя там вроде нет обозначения "граница слова", придется описывать наборы символов разделителей

Comment: @Mike слово - набор букв без символов и цифр

Comment: Но что из себя представляет таблица test? у нее только 1 поле которое содержит слова или несколько?

Comment: @tramway просто напишите подходящую под ваши данные регулярку для regexp_matches, по документации https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/functions-matching  я касати долистал ее до конца, там таки есть граница слова `\m` и `\M`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> create table test(how_to_use_dbfiddle) as
> values ('+ 1 -  Proc Enter one statement per Proc field 1 2')
>      , ('Fields Proc grow as you Proc type 5 6')
>      , ('Use the Proc [+] buttons to Proc add more % @ #')
>      , ('See examples Proc below for advanced Proc usage 9');
> ```

> ```
> with words_list AS (
>  select 
>    unnest(regexp_split_to_array(how_to_use_dbfiddle,' ')) as word
>  from test
> ) 
> select 
>   count(*) 
> from words_list
> where 
>   word = 'Proc'
> ```
>
> ```
> | count |
> | ----: |
> |     8 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1503dc9b1cdfad8a6d89a61ddc3458c5)*